# why do i get "error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using vs2012 and having the same problem. below is my sample source code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "list"
#include "algorithm"
#include "xutility"

using namespace std;

typedef struct Student{
   string name;
   int age;

  int operator==(list<Student>::iterator itr)
  {
    return (!strcmp(itr->name.c_str(),this->name.c_str()));
  }
}SStudent;


 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
    list<SStudent> myList;
    SStudent temp1;
    temp1.age = 10;
    temp1.name = "aaaa";

    myList.push_back(temp1);

    list<SStudent>::iterator itr;
     itr = std::find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), "aaaa");

    return 0;
 }
```

here is the error: 
Error   1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Student' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 3186

Comment: Did you mean to write this: `int operator==(list<Student>::iterator itr)` instead of `int operator==(Student student)`?

Comment: even though I do
----------------------------------------------------------------
  int operator==(Student stud)
  {
    return (!strcmp(stud.name.c_str(),this->name.c_str()));
  }
compiler does not like it and reports the same error


Error 1 error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Student' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 3186 1 ConsoleApplication3

Comment: `std::find` doesn't return an iterator. And you seem to switch between using `Student` and `SStudent`